# How to use Server.MapPath in jQuery JavaScript when deploying on Hosting Server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using `WebMethod` on my ASPXpage and I call it from jQuery on the same page like this:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Mypage.aspx/GetSomeData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: parameters,
                dataType: "json",
                success: AjaxSucceeded,
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
```

This works fine in my debug environment, but when I deploy on the hosting site it does not.
The problem seems to be in the URL because on the server the path would be different. So I  used `Server.MapPath` in various ways but none of them worked.

E.g

```
url: '<%= Server.MapPath("MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData")%>',
```

When I use the above code snippet it does not work on my machine. `MyPage` is in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need a tilde to start at the root of the app:

```
url: '<%= Server.MapPath("~/MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData")%>'
```

EDIT

Try using:

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/MyPage.aspx") %>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work, it gives 404 error. When i look at the Post in firebug it is looking at the following location http://localhost:1718/lmpweb/~/MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid URL: `MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData`.  Should it be: `MyPage.aspx?GetSomeData` or somesuch?

Comment: When I use MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData it works fine on my debug machine. When I use MyPage.aspx?GetSomeData it gives parse error.

Comment: When i use <%= ResolveUrl("~/MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData") it works fine on my debug machine but on the server it does not work